# The Eigenvalue Problem: Perturbation Theory

Tags: eigenvalues, perturbation

Let $\mathbf{K}$ be a square matrix and $\rho(\mathbf{K})$
is the spectral radius of $\mathbf{K}$. Then, If $\mathbf{M}= \mathbf{K}+\delta \mathbf{A}$ for very small $\delta$, I want to prove that

1. $$ \label{asrr1}
     \rho(\mathbf{M})=\rho(\mathbf{K})+\delta \langle \mathbf{u}, \mathbf{A}\mathbf{v} \rangle + O(\delta^{2}) 
   $$
   where $\mathbf{u}$ and $\mathbf{v}$ are respectively the left and right eigenvector of $\mathbf{K}$.
2. Additionally, by using 1, can we prove that
   $$
     \rho(\mathbf{M})=\rho(\mathbf{K})+\delta \rho^{\prime} (\mathbf{K})+ O(\delta^{2}) \;?
   $$
   That means, can we show $ \rho^{\prime} (\mathbf{K})= \langle \mathbf{u}, \mathbf{A} \mathbf{v} \rangle$?

where $\prime$ is a notation for derivative.

I am very grateful if someone shows me the sketch of the proof.  Also, I am very happy if you forward me a reference related to this, and I can read and understand more.

Thank you very much for your cooperation!

Comment: Could you please specify what you mean by "left and write eigenvector of $K$"? For which eigenvalue? Why are they unique? And if they are unique (up to scalar multiples), how do you normalize them?

Comment: Eigenvectors are never unique.  What normalization are you using?

Answer (score 2):

Counterexample: $$K = \pmatrix{0 & 1\cr 0 & 0\cr},\ \rho(K) = 0,\ {\bf u} = (0,1),\ {\bf v} = \pmatrix{1\cr 0\cr},\ 
 A = \pmatrix{1 & 0\cr 0 & 1\cr}$$
Normalize however you want, $({\bf u}, A {\bf v}) = 0$, but $\rho(K + \delta A) = |\delta|$.

Comment: Without any computation: If we are in the case when $u$ is not unique, then the smooth formula cannot hold for an arbitrary choice of $u,v,A$. However, the question remains if it should be just replaced by the bound with supremum over the corresponding generalized eigenspaces (with normalization $|u|=|v|=1$, of course), which would imply the sharp Lipschitz property instead of the differentiability.

Comment: Thanks All!
\\\



If I take the first result as true, then can I use the derivative definition to prove the second result?
 
 $$\rho^{\prime} (\mathbf{K})= \langle \mathbf{u}, \mathbf{A} \mathbf{v} \rangle=
\dfrac{\rho(\mathbf{K+\delta\mathbf{A}})-\rho(\mathbf{K})}{\delta},~~~~~~\delta \rightarrow 0
$$